# Meta-analysis of paired count data

Tags: confidence-interval, meta-analysis, count-data, paired-data

I have data from 70 studies reporting number of observed events in two time periods, one before Covid and one during the Covid pandemic. The duration of the timeperiods and the size of the population were the events occurred varies between the reports but are similar for the paired data within each study. There is no information about the size of the population so cannot use incidence rates. I have only paired counts of events

The hypothesis is that within each study the number of events would be the same in these periods. The alternative hypothesis is that the events increased, or decreased, during the covid pandemic.

How can I do the analysis? The problem is the denominator. Can I use the total number of events and estimate the RiskRatio as (percovid numbers/total numbers)/(precovid numbers/total numbers) ? Or simply use the Odds (percovid numbers)/(precovid numbers)? I think I need the CI for the meta-analysis as a mean to include the size of the study. I know how to do that for the RiskRatio but not for an odds?